# Is there a way to switch focus between windows in a single GTK application?

Tags: gtk, gtk3, pygtk

I'll write details in python b/c that's what I'm using but the same question should apply in C++.

Suppose I have a `Gtk.Application` instance that has two separate `Gtk.Window` objects attached. These are both displayed side by side when using the application. Let's call them window A and B

I want to trigger the application to switch focus between window A and window B, but I can't find a way to do it.

- The method: `Gtk.Window.set_focus(widget)` will switch the focus between widgets within the same window.
- The method: `Gtk.Widget.grab_focus()` does the same thing only it automatically targets the calling instance.
- The method: `Gtk.Application.get_windows()` returns a list of application windows in the order of most recent focus.

When I call `windowA.grab_focus()` while B is focused, it does nothing. Same effect for calling `windowA.set_focus(windowA)`

It seems like GTK only has the power to control intra-window focus changes and not focus changes between different windows. This could make sense as I can see why this functionality would be delegated to the window manager. But it still seems like there should be a way to do this.

Answer (score 4):

You probably want [GtkWindow.present()](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWindow.html#gtk-window-present). This will focus the window and raise it to the top. It will automatically focus the default widget.